# Gnuplot one-liner to generate a titled line for each row in a CSV file

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I've been trying to figure out gnuplot but haven't been getting anywhere for seemingly 2 reasons. My lack of understanding gnuplot set commands, and the layout of my data file. I've decided the best option is to ask for help.

Getting this gnuplot command into a ***one-liner is the hope***.

Example rows from my CSV data file (MyData.csv):

```
> _TitleRow1_,15.21,15.21,...could be more, could be less
> _TitleRow2_,16.27,16.27,101,55.12,...could be more, could be less
> _TitleRow3_,16.19,16.19,20.8,...could be more, could be less 
...(over 100 rows)
```

Contents of MyData.csv rows will always be a ***string as the first column for title***, followed by an undetermined amount of decimal values. (Each row gets appended to periodically, so ***specifying an open ended amount of columns to include is needed***)

What I'd like to happen is to generate a ***line graph showing a line for each row in the csv***, using the first column as a row title, and the following numbers generating the actual line.
This is the I'm trying:

```
gnuplot -e 'set datafile separator ","; set key autotitle columnhead; plot "MyData.csv"'
```

Which results in:

```
set datafile separator ","; set key autotitle columnhead; plot "MyData.csv"
                                                               ^
line 0: Bad data on line 2 of file MyData.csv
```

This looks like an amazing tool and I'm looking forward to learning more about it. Thanks in advance for any hints/assistance!

Comment: This is a very unfortunate format for gnuplot, but I think it can be done. What should the x-value be, the column-index minus 1? Do you really want to have over 100 titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datafile format is very unfortunate for gnuplot which prefers data in columns.
Although, you can also plot rows (which is not straightforward in gnuplot, but see [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67591829/7295599)). This requires a strict matrix, but the problem with your data is that you have a variable column count.

Actually, your CSV is not a "correct" CSV, because a CSV should have the same number of columns for all rows, i.e. if one row has less data than the row with maximum data the line should be filled with `,,,` as many as needed. That's basically what the script below is doing.

With this you can plot rows with the option `matrix` (check `help matrix`). However, you will get some warnings `warning: matrix contains missing or undefined values` which you can ignore.

Alternatively, you could transpose your data (with variable column count maybe not straightforward). Maybe there are external tools which can do it easily. With *gnuplot-only* it will be [a bit cumbersome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65576405/7295599) (and first you would have to fill your shorter rows as in the example below).
Maybe there is a simpler and better *gnuplot-only* solution which I am currently not aware of.

**Data:** `SO73099645.dat`

```
_TitleRow1_, 1.2, 1.3
_TitleRow2_, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5
_TitleRow3_, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4
```

**Script:**

```
### plotting rows with variable columns
reset session

FILE = "SO73099645.dat"

getColumns(s) = (sum [i=1:strlen(s)] (s[i:i] eq ',') ? 1 : 0) + 1

set datafile separator "\t"
colCount = 0
myNaNs = myHeaders = ''
stats FILE u (rowCount=$0+1, c=getColumns(strcol(1)), c>colCount ? colCount=c : 0) nooutput
do for [i=1:colCount] {myNaNs=myNaNs.',NaN' }

set table $Data
    plot FILE u (s=strcol(1),c=getColumns(s),s.myNaNs[1:(colCount-c)*4]) w table
unset table

set datafile separator ","
stats FILE u (myHeaders=sprintf('%s "%s"',myHeaders,strcol(1))) nooutput
myHeader(n) = word(myHeaders,n)

set key noenhanced

plot for [row=0:rowCount-1] $Data matrix u 1:3 every ::1:row::row w lp pt 7 ti myHeader(row+1)
### end of script
```

**As "one-liner":**

```
FILE = "SO/SO73099645.dat"; getColumns(s) = (sum [i=1:strlen(s)] (s[i:i] eq ',') ? 1 : 0) + 1; set datafile separator "\t"; colCount = 0; myNaNs = myHeaders = ''; stats FILE u (rowCount=$0+1, c=getColumns(strcol(1)), c>colCount ? colCount=c : 0) nooutput; do for [i=1:colCount] {myNaNs=myNaNs.',NaN' }; set table $Data; plot FILE u (s=strcol(1),c=getColumns(s),s.myNaNs[1:(colCount-c)*4]) w table; unset table; set datafile separator ","; stats FILE u (myHeaders=sprintf('%s "%s"',myHeaders,strcol(1))) nooutput; myHeader(n) = word(myHeaders,n); set key noenhanced; plot for [row=0:rowCount-1] $Data matrix u 1:3 every ::1:row::row w lp pt 7 ti myHeader(row+1)
```

**Result:**

[image]